# How to find out number of unique values in a column along with count of the unique values in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

As per the following data set I want no get the number of unique values and count of the unique values.

My data set:

```
Account_Type
Gold
Gold
Platinum
Gold
```

Output :

```
no of unique values : 2
unique values : [Gold,Platinum]
Gold : 3
Platinum :1
```

Comment: you may try set().

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting unique values in a column in pandas dataframe like in Qlik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759966/counting-unique-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-like-in-qlik)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `pd.value_counts`

```
pd.value_counts(df.Account_Type)

Gold        3
Platinum    1
Name: Account_Type, dtype: int64
```

Get number of unique as well

```
s = pd.value_counts(df.Account_Type)
s1 = pd.Series({'nunique': len(s), 'unique values': s.index.tolist()})
s.append(s1)

Gold                            3
Platinum                        1
nunique                         2
unique values    [Gold, Platinum]
dtype: object
```

---

***Alternate Approach***

```
df['col1'].value_counts(sort=True)
df['col1'].value_counts(sort=True, normalize=True) -> provides proportion
```

Comment: When applying this nice code to a categorical variable of a df I receive an error:
    
pd.value_counts(df.application_type)
s = pd.value_counts(df.application_type)
s1 = pd.Series({'nunique': len(s), 'unique values': s.index.tolist()})
s.append(s1)

TypeError: cannot append a non-category item to a CategoricalIndex

"application_type" is a category column from df.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set()` to remove duplicates and then calculate the length:

`len(set(data_set))`

To count the occurrence:

`data_set.count(value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    df['Account_Type].unique()
```

returns unique values of the specified column (in this case 'Account_Type') as a NumPy array.

All you have to do is use the len() function to find the no of unique values in the array.

```
    len(df['Account_Type].unique())
```

To find the respective counts of unique values, you can use value_counts()