# Counting unique values in a column in pandas dataframe like in Qlik?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, qlikview, qliksense

If I have a table like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'hID': [101, 102, 103, 101, 102, 104, 105, 101],
         'dID': [10, 11, 12, 10, 11, 10, 12, 10],
         'uID': ['James', 'Henry', 'Abe', 'James', 'Henry', 'Brian', 'Claude', 'James'],
         'mID': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C']
})
```

I can do `count(distinct hID)` in Qlik to come up with count of 5 for unique hID.  How do I do that in python using a pandas dataframe?  Or maybe a numpy array?  Similarly, if were to do `count(hID)` I will get 8 in Qlik.  What is the equivalent way to do it in pandas?

Comment: @piRSquared thanks. I could do something like  df[['dID','hID']].agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique']) and it works. But it does not work when combined with groupby. So df[['dID','hID']].groupby('mID').agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique']) says KeyError. is there a way to select particular columns and apply a condition?

Comment: Three ways  `df[['mID', 'dID','hID']].groupby('mID').agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique'])`

Comment: Or `df[['dID','hID']].groupby(df['mID']).agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique'])`

Comment: Or `df.groupby('mID')[['dID', 'hID']].agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique'])`

Answer (score 405, accepted):

Count distinct values, use `nunique`:

```
df['hID'].nunique()
5
```

Count only non-null values, use `count`:

```
df['hID'].count()
8
```

Count total values including null values, use the `size` attribute:

```
df['hID'].size
8
```

## Edit to add condition

Use boolean indexing:

```
df.loc[df['mID']=='A','hID'].agg(['nunique','count','size'])
```

OR using `query`:

```
df.query('mID == "A"')['hID'].agg(['nunique','count','size'])
```

Output:

```
nunique    5
count      5
size       5
Name: hID, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks! How do we add a condition? Like nunique for mID='A'?

Comment: How to count number of None values? I have a df of only None, and `.unique()` returns 0

Comment: @Gulzar Use.  `isna` like this  `df['col'].isna().sum()`

Comment: How to count distinct values, including nans? meaning `count` if no nans, or `count+1` if any nan exists?

Comment: @Gulzar  To get count of distinct values, you use nunique.  There is a parameter `dropna` default to True, but if you change it to False, it will count the distinct values and add one for NaN.  Example, `df['val'].nunique(dropna=False)`.

Answer (score 211):

If I assume data is the name of your dataframe, you can do :

```
data['race'].value_counts()
```

this will show you the distinct element and their number of occurence.

Comment: If you want the proportions for each unique item you can also do. `data['race'].value_counts(normalize=True)`

Answer (score 55):

Or get the number of unique values for each column:

```
df.nunique()

dID    3
hID    5
mID    3
uID    5
dtype: int64
```

---

New in `pandas 0.20.0` [**`pd.DataFrame.agg`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html)

```
df.agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique'])

         dID  hID  mID  uID
count      8    8    8    8
size       8    8    8    8
nunique    3    5    3    5
```

---

You've always been able to do an `agg` within a `groupby`.  I used `stack` at the end because I like the presentation better.

```
df.groupby('mID').agg(['count', 'size', 'nunique']).stack()


             dID  hID  uID
mID                       
A   count      5    5    5
    size       5    5    5
    nunique    3    5    5
B   count      2    2    2
    size       2    2    2
    nunique    2    2    2
C   count      1    1    1
    size       1    1    1
    nunique    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thanks! How do we add a condition? Like nunique for mID='A'?

Comment: @AlhpaDelta I added something at the end.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 11):

For unique count of your rows without duplications

`df['hID'].nunique()`

To know the number of each unique row content duplicated

`df['hID'].value_counts()`

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) in pandas:

```
df.hID.nunique()
# 5
```

Answer (score 2):

To count unique values in column, say `hID` of dataframe `df`, use:

```
len(df.hID.unique())
```

Comment: `df.hID.nunique()` is much more readable.

Answer (score 1):

**I was looking for something similar and I found another way you may help you**

- If you want to count the number of null values, you could use this function:

```
def count_nulls(s):
    return s.size - s.count()
```

- If you want to include NaN values in your unique counts, you need to pass dropna=False to the nunique function.

```
def unique_nan(s):
    return s.nunique(dropna=False)
```

- Here is a summary of all the values together using the titanic dataset:

```
from scipy.stats import mode

agg_func_custom_count = {
    'embark_town': ['count', 'nunique', 'size', unique_nan, count_nulls, set]
}
df.groupby(['deck']).agg(agg_func_custom_count)
```

*You can find more info [Here](https://pbpython.com/groupby-agg.html)*

Answer (score -4):

you can use unique property by using len function

> len(df['hID'].unique())
>   5