# Groupby Strings

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to create a new dataframe from an existing dataframe. I tried groupby but I didn't seem to sum up the strings as a whole number. Instead it returned many strings(colleges in this case).

[This is the original dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G30x.png)

[I tried groupby to get the number(whole number) of the colleges but it returned a many colleges(string) instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijLBs.png)

How do I return the number of colleges as an integer in the new column 'totalPlayer'? Please help.

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, a website where you should post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when you have a problem. pleas look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Hoping, I understand your question correctly.

You need to count the distinct values in college column.

Assuming **df** is the name of your data frame. Below code will help.

```
df['college'].nunique()
```

Helping Links - 
[Counting unique values in a column in pandas dataframe like in Qlik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759966/counting-unique-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-like-in-qlik)

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html

Comment: I just figured out how to do it. I guess my question was asking for the frequency of colleges but I didn't know how to put it into words. I found out calling .size() will return the number of frequency and turned it into a dataframe by .reset_index().

Comment: Ok, please confirm if my answer is not useful. so then I will delete this answer.

Comment: It is useful! Thank you