# count the unique occurrence of a col based on other col value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the follwing dataframe:

| Item | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | A1 | 11 |
| item1 | A1 | 12 |
| item2 | A1 | 21 |
| item2 | A1 | 22 |
| item3 | A1 | 31 |
| item3 | A1 | 11 |
| item4 | A1 | 12 |
| item4 | A1 | 21 |
| item5 | A2 | 22 |
| item5 | A2 | 31 |

how can I count the unique occurrence of each item when the type=A1? in the above example, it should be 4

I was thinking of something like this:

```
df['Type']=='A1'
list=df['Item'].unique()
occurance=list.str.len()
```

is there a better and easier way to do that?

Comment: Do not overwrite the built-in `list` function. Also, what is uneasy about the way you are currently doing it?

Comment: Use [Boolean Indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing) and [nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.nunique.html) `df.loc[df['Type'] == 'A1', 'Item'].nunique()` as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45760042/15497888) by [Scott Boston](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6361531/scott-boston)

Comment: Or [groupby nunique](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html) `df.groupby('Type')['Item'].nunique()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411596/15497888) by [Dan Allan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221924/dan-allan) if you want all unique item counts for all types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby('Type')['Item'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
Type
A1    4
A2    1
```

Only A1:

```
df.groupby('Type')['Item'].nunique()['A1']
```

Output: `4`

Answer (score 1):

```
len(df.loc[df["Type"]=="A1"]["Item"].unique())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this one liner: `df[df['Type']=='A1'][['Item']].drop_duplicates()`

Then you can convert the output into list if you need it.