# how do i find out how many different states in my data set

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am taking python course and trying to find out how many different states in my data set.

The column is 'ST'

i have attached screenshot [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting unique values in a column in pandas dataframe like in Qlik?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759966/counting-unique-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-like-in-qlik)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas.unique` to collect the unique elements of a series

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data={'ST': ['IL', 'WI',' LA', 'UT', 'IL']})
>>> pd.unique(df['ST'])
array(['IL', 'WI', ' LA', 'UT'], dtype=object)
```

and then use the `size` of the series

```
>>> pd.unique(df['ST']).size
4
```

similarly you can just call the `nunique` method off the series itself

```
>>> df['ST'].nunique()
4
```

Comment: perfect thank you cory.   I like the last one -  i will use that

Comment: Do you feel this is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45759966/counting-unique-values-in-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-like-in-qlik?